# Fetch JSON Array to ListView Android

Tags: android, arrays, json

I have response from server like this :

[image]

How to fetch that response to :

```
ListOrderItem orderItem = new ListOrderItem();

orderItem.setId_order(order_id);

orderItem.setUser_phone(order_user_phone);

orderItem.setUser_name(order_user_name);

orderItem.setVehicle_type(order_vehicle_type);

orderItem.setVehicle_brand(order_vehicle_merk);

orderItem.setVehicle_year(order_vehicle_year);

orderItem.setNote(order_note);

orderItem.setLongitude(order_longitude);

orderItem.setLatitude(order_latitude);

orderItem.setLocation(order_location);

arrayOrder.add(orderItem);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

Comment: Look into using Gson and/or Retrofit and see if they fit your needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
JSONObject response = new JSONObject(new String(yourResponseString));
int flag = response.getInt("code");
if ( flag == 200 ) {

  JSONArray message = response.getJSONArray("message");
   for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
       ListOrderItem orderItem = new ListOrderItem();
        JSONObject eachMessage = message.getJSONObject(i);
        orderItem.setId_order(eachMessage.getString("order_id"));
        orderItem.setUser_phone(eachMessage.getString("order_user_phone"));
        orderItem.setUser_name(eachMessage.getString("order_user_name"));
        orderItem.setVehicle_type(eachMessage.getString("order_vehicle_type"));
        orderItem.setVehicle_brand(eachMessage.getString("order_vehicle_merk"));
        orderItem.setVehicle_year(eachMessage.getString("order_vehicle_year"));
        orderItem.setNote(eachMessage.getString("order_note"));
        orderItem.setLongitude(eachMessage.getString("order_longitude"));
        orderItem.setLatitude(eachMessage.getString("order_latitude"));
        orderItem.setLocation(eachMessage.getString("order_location"));
        arrayOrder.add(orderItem);

   }

}
```

Comment: IT WORKS, THANKS FOR ADVICE !!

Comment: Happie coding.. :) Also please refer [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm) @ErzhaEmaszda